# Mongo query Not giving the expected result

Tags: mongodb

I have following document in my collection.

```
{
 "state": "approved",  
 "applicants": [   
],
 "user": "54a62c8bd334c57300d63af5", 
 "nonapplicants": [
  {
  "id": "54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm performing following query to get the documents that have either nonapplicants id "54a630d7d334c59501d63afd" or applicants id "54a630d7d334c59501d63afd" but it wont show any results.

```
{"$or":[{"applicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd","nonapplicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your query: your `$or` has only one argument, which is `{"applicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd","nonapplicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"}`. **What you want is:**

```
{"$or":[{"applicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"}, {"nonapplicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"}
```

**and not:**

```
{"$or":[{"applicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd", "nonapplicants.id":"54a630d7d334c59501d63afd"}
```

Comment: Good to note that the $or the OP provided meant `OR (applicants.id = '4454' AND applicants.id = 'ddd')`